# making a Question mark in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I am using the expression Blender 2010 draw in WPF and I am trying to make a question mark. This is what I have so far  and it looks bad:

```
  <ed:Arc Canvas.Left="33" Width="28" Height="24" Canvas.Top="22" ArcThickness="6" StartAngle="-45" EndAngle="140" Stretch="None" Fill ="Red"  />
        <ed:Arc Canvas.Left="45" Width="28" Height="26" Canvas.Top="37" ArcThickness="6" StartAngle="90" EndAngle="180" Stretch="None" Fill ="Red" RenderTransformOrigin="0.498,0.458"  >
            <ed:Arc.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="-179.625"/>
                    <TranslateTransform X="0.104" Y="1.427"/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </ed:Arc.RenderTransform>
        </ed:Arc>
        <Rectangle Canvas.Left="46" Canvas.Top="46" Width="6" Height="19" Stretch="Fill" Fill="Red"  />
        <Ellipse Canvas.Left="46"  Width="6" Height="6"   Canvas.Bottom="20"   Fill="Red" Canvas.Top="70" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.477,-0.363"  />
```

[enter image description here][1]

Updated: I just tried this :

```
  <Path x:Name="Information"  Canvas.Left="25" Canvas.Top="25"   Stretch="Fill" Width="50" Height="50"  Data="M9,89a81,81 0 1,1 0,2zm51-14c0-13 1-19 8-26c7-9 18-10 28-8c10,2 22,12 22,26c0,14-11,19-15,22c-3,3-5,6-5,9v22m0,12v16">
            <Path.Fill>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="Lime"/>
            </Path.Fill>
        </Path>
```

but it still look bad really bad[enter image description here][2]

please see up picture.
I got the information for the Sgv from
https://commons.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:SVG_Question_marks
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9X6A.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKY6e.png

Comment: Personally, i would just use a path. Build or obtain a geometry. There's a free library https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/metrostudio one of the options lets you choose a font and character to generate a geometry. Or if you have a picture of ehst you want, inkscapeis another free tool. You can auto trace a bitmap. Or find an svg with a question mark in it and grab the path out that.https://commons.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:SVG_Question_marks

Comment: Much simpler, use a TextBlock element with an appropriate font.

Comment: @ Andy please see my updated,

Comment: @ clemens, I am trying to make a custom button

Comment: You can put a `?` of any font you want on a button.  Why draw one from scratch?

Comment: @ Flydog57, I am making custom automation  buttons like these : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UY6obw-PJvo&t=490s

Comment: Maybe FontAwesome?  Not sure how well it mixes and matches with WPF, but ...

Comment: Here you go: https://www.nuget.org/packages/FontAwesome.WPF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are wanting to set up using paths in your WPF project.

Here is one example of doing this. There are many.

[You can get your paths for example from Material Designs](https://materialdesignicons.com/) just click on an icon and then look at the SVG or XAML canvas where they have the Path.Data information.

For example below I have copied the data for a question mark and added it to a Viewbox.  These ViewBox elements you can have in your Window.Resources or in a Resource file.

```
<Viewbox x:Key="questionMark">
            <Canvas Width="512"
                    Height="512">
                <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                    <TranslateTransform X="0"
                                        Y="0" />
                </Canvas.RenderTransform>
                <Canvas.Resources />
                <Canvas>
                    <Path xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                          Fill="Black"
                          Opacity="1.00">
                        <Path.Data>
                            <PathGeometry Figures="M10,19H13V22H10V19M12,2C17.35,2.22 19.68,7.62 16.5,11.67C15.67,12.67 14.33,13.33 13.67,14.17C13,15 13,16 13,17H10C10,15.33 10,13.92 10.67,12.92C11.33,11.92 12.67,11.33 13.5,10.67C15.92,8.43 15.32,5.26 12,5A3,3 0 0,0 9,8H6A6,6 0 0,1 12,2Z"
                                          FillRule="NonZero" />
                        </Path.Data>
                    </Path>
                </Canvas>
            </Canvas>
        </Viewbox>
```

To Use it you just add a Grid;

```
           <Grid Background="Yellow" Width="50" Height="50">
                <Grid.OpacityMask>
                    <VisualBrush Visual="{StaticResource questionMark}" />
                </Grid.OpacityMask>
            </Grid>
```

Result looks like this;
[image: questionmarkimage]